# Why bash doesn't execute code after curl?

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash code like this:

```
set -x
status=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' $nb_url)
echo "got status code = $status"
```

Here is the debug output that I got:

```
++ curl --write-out '%{http_code}' 'https://myurl:54516/?token=89835a6dd0793eda'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed connect to myurl:54516; Connection refused
+ status=000
```

So the status is set to 000 but the echo never execute. Do you know why?

Comment: Do you have `set -e` somewhere earlier in the script or something like that?

Comment: I got the same output with set -e.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect `set -e` to cause the observed behavior, it would cause the script to exit after that line

Comment: Ah, i saw set -e in the few lines above that script. Thanks very much for pointing it out.

Comment: You understand that he's telling you you need to remove the `set -e` or at least add `set +x` before the `curl` line, right?

Comment: This is why you should not use `set -e` unless 1) you are aware of each command that might have a non-zero exit status and 2) you know which of those could cause the shell to exit under `set -e`.

Comment: You ought to put that down as the answer @EricRenouf

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I had a 'set -e' in my script

```
set -e    # <-- Remove this line it works
set -x
status=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' $nb_url)
echo "got status code = $status"
```